# Rails category select display :name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I've created a category model and several instances with different :names, so users can add the products they list for sale into a category. The only problem is here:

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.all, :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

The categories display correctly when I use this code, but if I try to do Category.all.name they don't display. I'm probably just really tired, but how do I display the :name attribute of each category rather than a crytic instance identifyer?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `collection_select`:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select One' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Category.all` will return an array of categories,

if you want names of all categories,

try this,

> Category.all.map(&:name)

you probably need to modify the `select tag` like this

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.all.map(&:name), :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails has a very useful method like [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

> as a shortcut to select one or more attributes without loading a bunch
>   of records just to grab the attributes you want.

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.pluck(:name), :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

But that's not a Rails way, uses Class in views, you must declare @variable in the controller and pass it to the select helper:

controller action:

```
@names = Category.pluck(:name)
```

in views:

```
<%= f.select :category, @names, :prompt => "Select One" %>
```